# Tabs on HomePage

Tags: ionic-framework

im trying to make tabs in my HomePage, but the page isnt loading when i put the HomePage as the selected index in tabs, here's my Code:

**home.ts:**

```
...
export class HomePage {
  public isConnected: Boolean= true;

  homeRoot = HomePage;
  aRoot = SigninPage;
  bRoot = SignupPage;
...
```

**home.html:**

```
///SOME CONTENT
<ion-tabs selectedIndex="0" *ngIf="isConnected">
                <ion-tab [root]="homeRoot" tabTitle="Home"></ion-tab>
                <ion-tab [root]="aRoot" tabTitle="Home"></ion-tab>
                <ion-tab [root]="bRoot" tabTitle="Home"></ion-tab>

            </ion-tabs>
```

**app.compenents.ts:**

```
//IMPORTS

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new page TabsPage.

//Tabs.ts

```
export class TabsPage{
public isConnected: Boolean= true;

homeRoot = HomePage;
aRoot = SigninPage;
bRoot = SignupPage;
```

//Tabs.html

```
 <ion-tabs selectedIndex="0" *ngIf="isConnected">
            <ion-tab [root]="homeRoot" tabTitle="Home"></ion-tab>
            <ion-tab [root]="aRoot" tabTitle="Home"></ion-tab>
            <ion-tab [root]="bRoot" tabTitle="Home"></ion-tab>

  </ion-tabs>
```

//app.component.ts

```
 //IMPORTS
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = TabsPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: 
SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont want the tabs to appear if the isConnected is False, i cant do that if i use your solution :/

Comment: I added ` <ion-nav [root]="rootPage" *ngIf="!isConnected"></ion-nav> ` to the tabs.html and ` rootPage= HomePage;` to the tabs.ts it worked THANKS